# SQL Server - preventing SQL injection

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I have been looking through old posts but am seeing some conflicting info on this. I have a SQL Server database and I am talking to it with C# code (.Net 4.5). I used stored procedures to do everything in the database and parameterising the inputs when I make a call.

I would like to lock down the database so that it won't accept SQL code and will only respond to calls to the stored procedures. Is this possible?

Comment: Although there is no setting to disallow ad-hoc SQL, you grant only EXECUTE permissions on stored procedures, which would allow data access only via procs (assuming an unbroken ownership chain) and prevent ad-hoc access by non-privileged accounts.

Comment: @Dan - I've taken a look at this and it looks like it will work. Many thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no setting to disallow ad-hoc SQL entirely, you could grant only `EXECUTE` permissions on only the stored procedures called directly by application code.  Permissions on objects referenced by stored procedures are not needed as long as the ownership chain is unbroken, meaning that the stored procedure and referenced schema/objects are owned by the same user (typically dbo).  This method will prevent ad-hoc access by non-privileged accounts.

Be aware ownership chaining does not apply when dynamic SQL is used with the procs.  If procs have dynamic SQL (with securely built SQL and parameterized), you can sign the module with a certificate to provide the needed permissions from within the proc without granting users direct permissions on objects referenced by the dynamic SQL statement.  See [giving permissions through stored procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) for details and examples.

Be sure to specify `CommandType.StoredProcedure` on all `SqlCommand` objects to ensure parameters must be passed separately.  Although it is possible to execute stored procedures using `CommandType.Text`, more attention to detail is needed to do securely.